# Zend_Cache cache file disappears

Tags: zend-framework, zend-cache

I have a zend cache which stores an array from the db. The cache can be read & updated fine. But the actual cache file seems to disappear after a day or so. I thought that adding `automatic_cleaning_factor = 0` would solve this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
$frontendOptions = array(
    'caching' => true,
    'cache_id_prefix' => 'mysite_blah',
    'lifetime' => 14400, # 4 hours
    'automatic_serialization' => true,
    'automatic_cleaning_factor' => 0,
);
$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/../../cache/zend_cache/"
);
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);

if(!$result = $cache->load('test_blah'))
{
    // run SQL
    ...    
    $cache->save($my_array_from_db, 'test_blah');
}
else
{
     $result = $cache->load('test_blah');
}
```

The page which uses this cache isn't very popular, not sure if that has anything to do with it..... Any ideas?

Comment: can't i have a comment there...?

Comment: eh i mean the cache will disappear after  4 hours. Eh sorry looks like automatic_cleaning_factor should stop this.. maybe the sysem cleans up the cache dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain why your file is vanishing, I think something is missing from your sample that is probably removing the cache file. I can however have a few notes that might help you out...

I think you're misinterpreting the `automatic_cleaning_factor` parameter.  This does not disable your cache from expiring. This only disables the cache frontend from automatically cleaning *any* cache that may have expired when you call the `save()` method.

When you `load()` your cache it still gets tested for validity, and if invalid, it gets ignored and your database will be queried for fresh data.  You can pass `true` as a second parameter on the `load()` to ignore the validity test.

**However** you should probably just set your `lifetime` to a very long time instead of overriding cache validation, because it's there for a reason.

Also, this code can be simplified:

```
if(!$result = $cache->load('test_blah')) {
    // run SQL
    ...    
    $cache->save($my_array_from_db, 'test_blah');
} else {
     $result = $cache->load('test_blah');
}
```

To:

```
if(!$result = $cache->load('test_blah')) {
    // run SQL
    ...   
    $result = $my_array_from_db;
    $cache->save($result, 'test_blah');
}
```

The `else` is not needed because `$result` from your cache is assigned in the `if()` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'll put these into action and report back if it fixes my problem.

Comment: Thought: if the load() validation fails, does it remove the cache file at that point? Or it the cache file only removed/updated in save()

Comment: Since removing the unnecessary else block, this problem has disappeared.